# Howto Monitor several web applications (with JMX) on a Tomcat server?

Tags: web-applications, tomcat, jmx

Is there a way to monitor CPU and memory consumption of an individual web application on a `Tomcat` server?

I have `Tomcat` opening all the web applications under its JVM, so I only see one JVM and cannot monitor each web-app by itself.
The web-apps are sealed WAR files and I cannot tamper with the Java code either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the official answer (to a very similar question/suggestion) is to [run multiple Tomcat instances](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51366).

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to monitor in web application? Servlets, ejbs....? If you pass corresponding objectname string as part of your jmx query, it will list all servlets from all applications hosted on the jvm. This way you can monitor individual application on that jvm.

Comment: Ok. But can I monitor CPU usage and memory consumption per object in the JVM, or will I get the entire JVM's stats?

Comment: Servlet, ejb etc., they are per object. You can get whoule JVM stats also.

Comment: I couldn't monitor the servlet's info. Say the tomcat's IP is 10.0.0.1, I'd monitor it via 10.0.0.1:8999.
The servlet is a webapp called, say, MyServlet. location: 10.0.0.1/MyServlet. I got this obj-name: Catalina:j2eeType=Servlet,name=appServlet,WebModule=//localhost/MyServlet,J2EEApplication=none,J2EEServer=none.
Now what?