# Monitoring multiple java applications at once with one zabbix java gateway

Tags: java, tomcat8, jmx, zabbix

I'm setting JMX monitoring with Zabbix 4.0. The Zabbix server, deployed applications, Tomcat8, Zabbix Java gateway and Zabbix agent are all in the same host, as it's for testing purposes.

So, I've linked the Tomcat and generic Java application templates. But I need to monitor the Java applications separately. For example, I need to know the resources consumption of each Java app. I need to get the return values of some objects of some Java apps.

So how to specify the application in items configuration?

Comment: Are you running multiple tomcat instances, or how do wish to access them for monitoring? Usually you will need a JMX port for each JVM instance which is running.

Comment: Hi @AndréSchild, so, I'm running a single tomcat instance, with several java applications. I've set the JMX settings in setenv.sh, so the tomcat starts acessible via JMX.  So, the JMX port, at zabbix frontend, matches the jmx remote access port at the setenv.sh.  So, what now?

Comment: You have to add the JMX template for your application to zabbix and then it should find things. But what is available depends on the JMX implemented in your applications. https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/tomcat

Comment: Hi @AndréSchild, so, I guess that these templates will monitor the JVM as a whole, instead of monitor the app specific things. We'd like to use the Spring Boot Actuator to be able to access the default and user-defined endpoints.  For example, /app1/metrics, /app2/beans. So, is it possible to specify the app in zabbix?

Comment: I suggest you try to look into your tomcat and the apps with JConsole, so you see what it's exposed from tomcat and your apps. You will see key names, which you then can use in Zabbix to monitor the items. These would then be something like `jmx["java.lang:type=Runtime",VmVersion]` in Zabbix

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629726/howto-monitor-several-web-applications-with-jmx-on-a-tomcat-server .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howto Monitor several web applications (with JMX) on a Tomcat server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629726/howto-monitor-several-web-applications-with-jmx-on-a-tomcat-server)

Comment: HI @AndréSchild, it's a bit hard for me to understand these java world stuff, as I'm a sysadmin trying to help the java developers team. So, in your example, where is the specification of the java app? I can't see any identification of the app in ```jmx["java.lang:type=Runtime",VmVersion]```

Comment: @FellipeTheophiloBarata The example I showed shou will retrievbe the jvm version of the tomcat. If this works, you can then go a step furter and look at the apps inside the jvm. Bus as long as the first step does not work you should first fix this

Comment: Thank you @AndréSchild, I make it works. After seeing in jConsole, I could specify the context name like this:
```jmx["Catalina:type=WebResourceRoot,host=localhost,context=/cep",stateName]```

Comment: @AndréSchild, although I can monitor specific context like the example above, my main objective is to monitor metrics given by the spring actuator of the resource servers, eg: mem, mem.free, threads.started and so on.

Comment: @AndréSchild I used the swagger tool to make a http get request to two applications and watch the results.

Comment: @AndréSchild The address is like http://10.1.20.152:8080/app1/metrics and http://10.1.20.152:8080/app2/metrics and the result is a json with many metrics of them. The problem is the results are the same. I've put it into a zabbix graph and used the ab(apache benchmark) and did a stress test to app1 , and the values grew together. Do you have and idea of what's wrong?

Comment: You will have to see if your app developer did separate them correctly